# Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 512. Shapes are [0] and [512]

Tags: tensorflow

run:
python .\main.py

```
import os
import copy
import time
import argparse
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from application.face.src.align import detect_face
from application.face.src.facenet import get_model_filenames, prewhiten

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
model_path = './application/face/src/20180408-102900'
#graph = tf.get_default_graph()#tf.compat.v1
session =tf.compat.v1.Session()#tf.compat.v1
#tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() 
tf.disable_v2_behavior() 
try:
    model_exp = os.path.expanduser(model_path)
    meta_file, ckpt_file = get_model_filenames(model_exp)
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_exp, meta_file), input_map=None)#tf.compat.v1
    saver.restore(session, os.path.join(model_exp, ckpt_file))
    graph = session.graph
    images_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    embeddings = graph.get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
    phase_train_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
   
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)


def parse_arguments(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('image_files', type=str, nargs='+', help='Images to compare')
    parser.add_argument('--image_size', type=int,
                        help='Image size (height, width) in pixels.', default=160)
    parser.add_argument('--margin', type=int,
                        help='Margin for the crop around the bounding box (height, width) in pixels.', default=44)
    parser.add_argument('--gpu_memory_fraction', type=float,
                        help='Upper bound on the amount of GPU memory that will be used by the process.', default=1.0)
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


def load_and_align_data(image_paths, image_size, margin, gpu_memory_fraction):
    minsize = 20  # minimum size of face
    threshold = [0.6, 0.7, 0.7]  # three steps's threshold
    factor = 0.709  # scale factor
    with tf.Graph().as_default():#tf
        gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_memory_fraction)#tf
        sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False))#tf
        with sess.as_default():
            pnet, rnet, onet = detect_face.create_mtcnn(sess, None)

    tmp_image_paths = copy.copy(image_paths)
    img_list = []
    for image in tmp_image_paths:
        img = misc.imread(os.path.expanduser(image), mode='RGB')
        img_size = np.asarray(img.shape)[0:2]
        bounding_boxes, _ = detect_face.detect_face(img, minsize, pnet, rnet, onet, threshold, factor)
        if len(bounding_boxes) < 1:
            image_paths.remove(image)
            print("can't detect face, remove ", image)
            continue
        det = np.squeeze(bounding_boxes[0, 0:4])
        bb = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.int32)
        bb[0] = np.maximum(det[0] - margin / 2, 0)
        bb[1] = np.maximum(det[1] - margin / 2, 0)
        bb[2] = np.minimum(det[2] + margin / 2, img_size[1])
        bb[3] = np.minimum(det[3] + margin / 2, img_size[0])
        cropped = img[bb[1]:bb[3], bb[0]:bb[2], :]
        aligned = misc.imresize(cropped, (image_size, image_size), interp='bilinear')
        prewhitened = prewhiten(aligned)
        img_list.append(prewhitened)
    images = np.stack(img_list)
    return images
def get_user_data(filename, type):
    origin_data_path = './application/data/originUserFaceData/'
    img_path = './upload/' + filename + '.' + type + '.png'
    args = parse_arguments([img_path])
    time_start = time.time()
    print('开始处理:' + filename + '.' + type)
    images = load_and_align_data(args.image_files, args.image_size, args.margin, args.gpu_memory_fraction)
    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default() as sess:
            feed_dict = {images_placeholder: images, phase_train_placeholder: False}
            emb = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
            np.savetxt(origin_data_path + filename + '.' + type + '.txt', emb[0])
    time_end = time.time()
    print('处理结束:' + filename + '.' + type + ',耗时:', end='')
    print('%.2f' % (time_end - time_start))
    if os.access(origin_data_path + filename + '.' + type + '.txt', os.F_OK):
        return True
    return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_arguments(['./face/src/20180408-102900', './face/src/q2.jpg'])
```

Error:    non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
Node 'gradients/InceptionResnetV1/Bottleneck/BatchNorm/cond/FusedBatchNorm_1_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad' has an _output_shapes attribute inconsistent with the Graph
Def for output #3: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 512. Shapes are [0] and [512].

Comment: Which line gets that error?